# Is there a reason to store a SSH private key in a Salt Pillar instead of a file as part of a State?

Tags: configuration-management, saltstack

I have a set of systems (in AWS) that all need passwordless SSH access to one another. I've written a Salt state that copies a keypair (public/private SSH-RSA keys that I previously generated) and adds the appropriate entry to the user's authorized_keys file.

Right now I store the public and private keys as files in the Salt state and source them in my state definition. However, I noticed in the [salt.states.file.managed() documentation](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.managed) that they provide an example that stores the private key in Pillar and then uses `contents_pillar` to get the contents of the private key.

Is there a reason I might want to store my private (or even public) key contents in Pillar instead of just a file in the state's directory? I'm not sure if there's a security advantage placing it there since the contents will end up on every system anyways. I've used Pillar for a few other things, but wasn't sure if there was a good case to use it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**All states are readable from all minions**, so someone (with the proper permissions) logged in any of your minion could read the private keys you store in the states.

**Pillar data can be restricted to the relevant minions**. This is where you store anything that is confidential to one or only some minions.

You should read the pillar documentation page: http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/pillar/index.html

There's this note:

> Storing sensitive data
>
> Unlike state tree, pillar data is only available for the targeted
>   minion specified by the matcher type. This makes it useful for storing
>   sensitive data specific to a particular minion.